# I want to know the difference between rscss and bem

Tags: bem, rscss

I don't understand the difference between RSCSS vs BEM. Someone says RSCSS and someone says BEM.

Pls let me know the difference that

Answer (score 4):

RSCSS is just BEM extended with some additional thoughts and experience of the crew who created it.

For example RSCSS states

- one level nesting to ping specificity a bit
- no double dash / lodash on modifier / elements 
  etc.

you can treat RSCSS as one of BEM modification (with some additional hints).

Answer (score 0):

When working with **RSCSS** you should think in components. Each piece of UI should be thought as an individual component.

example:

```
.signup-form {
   .inputfield {
     ...
   }
   .submitbtn {
     ...

     &.-inverted {
       ..
     }
   }
}
```

**BEM** methodology is based on the Block - Element - Modifier system, and here for every element unique selector should be used.

example:

```
.form { }
.form__input { }
.form__submit { }
.form__submit--wide { }
```

More about this theme read in [this CSS formatting text](https://kolosek.com/css-formatting/).